# Magento - How can I tell if I'm on a "My Account" page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'd like to add something to the top of the page on my Magento site, but only if the customer is in the "My Account" section. I'll be adding it to `/app/design/frontend/xxxx/xxxx/template/page/html/header.phtml`. How can I detect if the customer is in the "My Account" section?

I've found a few ways that don't work, the closest being `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName()`, which doesn't give a rock-solid way of checking if I'm in the "My Account" section.

These pages all have `<update handle="customer_account" />` in the XML, is there a way I can get the handle of the current page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magento way of doing it would be to edit your `local.xml` file.

There you should use the `customer_account_index` handle like this:

```
<customer_account_index>
  <reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="new_customer_data" template="page/html/customer.phtml"/>
  </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Create the `page/html/customer.phtml` with the data that you want.

And in `template/page/html/header.phtml` write `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('new_customer_data') ?>`

Another way is:

```
<?php $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
echo $action->getFullActionName('_');
if($action->getFullActionName('_')=="customer_account_index")
{

}?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked really well. I did it slightly differently, I placed the `<reference>` tag in the `<customer_account>` tag instead of the '<customer_account_index>'. This had the advantage of applying the update to all customer account pages instead of just the "Account Dashboard". In addition, some custom menus that I've added to the customer account include the `<update handle="customer_account" />` tag, so it works on those too. Thank you very much for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In layout page

```
<customer_account_index translate="label">
    <label>Custom Page</label>
        <reference name="header">
        <block type="page/header" name="header">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>your_custom_header_template_path/yourcustomheader.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
</customer_account_index>
```

Reference links:

http://www.atwix.com/magento/how-to-change-the-header-of-magento-cms-page/

http://istockphp.com/magento/adding-custom-page-to-the-customer-account-dashboard/